# Good way to clone an object

Tags: c#, .net

I have to clone some Entity, then I wrote this piece of code.

```
public override object Clone()
{
  var CloneUser = base.Clone() as FMSUser;

  CloneUser.Username = this.Username;
  CloneUser.IsEnabled = this.IsEnabled;
  CloneUser.IsNeedPasswordReset = this.IsNeedPasswordReset;
  CloneUser.LastName = this.LastName;
  CloneUser.FirstName = this.FirstName;
  CloneUser.MiddleName = this.MiddleName;
  CloneUser.DistributorID = this.DistributorID;
  CloneUser.IsLocked = this.IsLocked;

  return CloneUser;
}
```

But then my coworker sent me this code, saying it's better to clone this way, but can't tell me why :

```
public FMSUser(FMSUser user)
  : EntityBase(user)
{   
  this.Username = user.Username;
  this.IsEnabled = user.IsEnabled;
  this.IsNeedPasswordReset = user.IsNeedPasswordReset;
  this.LastName = user.LastName;
  this.FirstName = user.FirstName;
  this.MiddleName = user.MiddleName;
  this.DistributorID = user.DistributorID;
  this.IsLocked = user.IsLocked;
}
public override object Clone()
{
  return new FMSUser(this);
}
```

**Can anynone explain me why the second way is better?**

Comment: I have to agree with your coworker, his code leaves construction logic inside a constructor. Now this question isn't quite on-topic for this site, it's mostly opinion-based. Perhaps you want to post the class and its base type for a peer review?

Comment: @Mat'sMug I think this is on-topic. Although I think the answer can probably be found in an old StackOverflow question somewhere.

Comment: This is a common question, and you can google it using the terms ["Copy Constructor" and "Clonable"](https://www.google.ca/#hl=en&q=clone+or+copy-constructor+C%23) - Like Java, it appears that Copy-Constructor is the better choice in C#.

Comment: Of course this is a shallow copy of an entity only by convention, we do not know if `this.Username = user.Username;` is copying the reference or creating a new string with the same value, right? (I do not know .NET that well. I'm commenting making the analogy with Java.)

Comment: `public FMSUser(FMSUser user) : EntityBase(user)` This won't compile in C#. Is your colleague by any chance a C++ programmer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not listing your base class, but because of the override and the method's signature in the derived type, I'm assuming something like this:

```
public abstract class EntityBase : ICloneable
{
   //...
   public abstract object Clone();
}
```

Here's what [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.clone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says about `ICloneable` (emphasis mine):

> An implementation of Clone can perform either a deep copy or a shallow
>   copy. In a deep copy, all objects are duplicated; in a shallow copy,
>   only the top-level objects are duplicated and the lower levels contain
>   references. Because callers of Clone cannot depend on the method
>   performing a predictable cloning operation, **we recommend that
>   ICloneable not be implemented in public APIs**.

From that perspective, it's better to consider that "cloning" operation as nothing more than *construction* of a type - passing `this` to a constructor, and returning the created instance, sounds like a better plan.

Now, given that a `FMSUser` can be constructed from another instance, I don't really see a need for the `Clone` method to even exist at all. On top of it all, it returns an `object`, and you should avoid exposing `System.Object` in your public interfaces.

Consider this:

```
var clone = new FMSUser(existing); // "clone" is FMSUser.
```

Versus this:

```
var clone = existing.Clone(); // "clone" is System.Object, requires a cast to get a FMSUser.
```

---

Side note:

```
var CloneUser = base.Clone() as FMSUser;
```

`CloneUser` should be named `cloneUser`, or simply `clone`. By using *PascalCase*, you're breaking the naming convention for locals and parameters, which should be *camelCase*.

Comment: Always Giving good answers.  good reading here.

Comment: Of course MSDN remark is only relevant for `System.IClonable`. If you define an interface `MyNameSpace.IClonable<T>` or `MyNameSpace.IDeepClonable<T>` with deep clone semantic explicitly stated in documentation (and name) both objections, re type safety and re semantic ambiguity becomes moot.